# How to non-destructively bevel and extrude a mesh intersection?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel, procedural

In Blender 2.93/2.92, I am looking for ways to more easily create hard surface structures with doorways/archways that are extruded above the surface, in a non-destructive way that allows for quick prototyping.

When trying to use the bevel modifier on a boolean object, the bevel profile only cuts in to the surface.  Is there a way to use modifiers to get the beveled edges to extrude above the base surface, using the boolean modifier?

Reference screenshots.

1. A cube with some extra lines cut into a face. Faces inset where hole is desired.
2. Extruded the boundary face-loop above the original surface. Extruded the inset faces below the original surface
3. Unsuccessful attempt at creating this non-destructively. Bevel after boolean difference only cuts "in" to the surface, does not create any geometry "above" the surface
   [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I still don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, or failing to do. Maybe instead of providing a pair of distant, goal-based, before-and-after shots, you could provide a sequence of close-up, procedure-based, step-by-step shots.

Comment: I've updated the original post with some more screenshots.Hopefully they better illustrate the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should be able to solve this by using the bevel modifier limited to a vertex group.

First, go to the Object Data tab in the properties pane (the green one, can't miss it) and open Vertex Groups.  Hit the "+" button to create one.

[image: Create a vertex group]

Then, select the vertices you want to bevel in Edit mode.  While the group you just created is selected, click the "Assign" button underneath the vertex group list.

[image: Assign the vertex group]

Third, go to the Modifiers tab (the one with the wrench) and add a Bevel modifier.  In the "Limit Method" drop-down, select Vertex Group.

[image: Bevel Modifier]

Finally, select the vertex group you created earlier.  Play with the numbers a bit, and you should be good!

[image: the final product]

Comment: I appreciate the information, but the question isn't really about the basics of the bevel modifier, its about a specific use case - making the new geometry come out both above and below the plane of the specified edges, and doing it based on the intersection between two meshes, instead of manually modeling the the base shape.